# Linq to SQL: If left hand side of a join condition equates to NULL, Object reference exception is thrown

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Here's my query:

```
from f in DataAccess.Data.FList
join fA in DataAccess.Data.FAppsList on f.ID equals fA.fID into fApps
from fA in fApps.Where(fA => fA.Year == reportYear).DefaultIfEmpty() 
join fSrc in DataAccess.Data.FSourcesList on new { ID = fA.sourceID, CropYear = reportYear } 
equals new { ID = fSrc.ID, CropYear = fSrc.CropYear }
```

I get Object reference null exception if fA == null. I am doing a left join on fA so it could be either null or not null value. How do I rewrite this section of query so that the query does not throw exception if fA is null.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common construct in the [ternary conditional operator (`?:`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) which can be used to *safeguard* invoking a member on a `null-valued` expression is:

```
foo != null ? foo.bar : anExpressionThatDoesNotUseFoo
```

In context:

```
new {
  ID = fA != null ? fA.sourceID : 0, // or as appropriate
  ..
}
```